# Chrome autofill yellow background goes above icon in form field

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, icons, autofill

Jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/dlnkprs/MR33L/

I'm creating a different style for a Wordpress login form. I've put an icon in both username and password field. Displaying this:

[image: Normal]

But.. when you use Chrome's autofill the background turns yellow and the icons disappear:

[image: Chrome autofill]

Any idea how to solve this so the icons are still visible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dlnkprs/MR33L/. Don't know if it's gonna work with jsfiddle because you need to have autofill.

Answer (score 1):

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #fff inset;
}
```

This will make it so the background of the inputs are white, and you can obviously change the colour to whatever you like. Unfortunately I can't find any way to make the icons appear in front of the yellow background, so the best thing I can recommend is to turn autocomplete off in each input element by adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to them.

Sorry I couldn't have been more helpful.

Comment: Then I need to edit Wordpress' core files (wp-login.php). That's no option because of updates. Any way to add the code on a different manner?

Comment: To add the attributes to the elements you would need to edit the file, I can't think of any way to do it otherwise. Surely you could just edit it every time there is an update?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `span` element just at the left of each input box with the icon as background. With this you separate the input from the actual icon and **keep the autocomplete** functionality.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pt8Rb/